# Is possible to use new Kinect Xbox instead of Kinect sensor windos (v1)?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have build some application that use Kinect sensor Windows (v1). Now this sensor is not available from all web, there is only Kinect v2 (FOR XBOX). Now my question is, I can use my code with this new Kinect sensor? and it is possible use to same function of the Kinect 1 with this new Kinect?
I know that if I want to connect xbox on my PC I must by tha adapter, but my doubt is on the function of this new kinect and if I must change also my code in my application to use this new Kinect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API changed between Kinect V1 (SDK 1.8) to Kinect V2 (SDK 2).
Most of your code should be the same, but you must adapt your code to the new API if you want use V2.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adapting you're code to the new API, you also have to make sure you're PC meets [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782036.aspx) for Kinect v2:

- **Windows 8+** (Windows 10 is still problematic)
- 64 bit (x64) processor
- 4 GB Memory (or more)
- I7 3.1 GHz (or higher)
- **USB 3.0** host controller (Intel or Renesas chipset) - Kinect v2 is very picky about the USB 3.0 controller.
- DX11 capable graphics adapter